# How to programmatically find out what channels are part of a given YouTube network?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

Looks like there is no official YouTube API to find list of YouTube networks or what channels are part of a given network. Any ideas how to find that information?

If there is no direct method, what algorithm does socialblade.com use get approximate listings?

Comment: You didnt mean to get the channel the video belongs right? Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856445/get-xml-attribute-with-simplexml/12856747

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is the way sites such as socialblade or channelmeter get the networked channels. But this is the way i did it.

Say i visit this video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8AZT40gH5E

In the meta tags information of a networked channel, there is an attribute `<meta name=attribution content=JamieOliver/>` (As example) which actually specifies the network that channel belongs to. So what i did was one video from the channel i'm working with, and use a small function like this:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8AZT40gH5E");
echo $network = $tags['attribution'];
```

And you have the Network the channel is associated with.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you can get this information using the v3 API at this time, but I believe what socialblade is calling *networks* is the content owner or 'Partner Name'.

> In an API response, a feed entry contains a partner video if the entry contains a `<media:credit>` tag for which the value of the yt:type attribute is partner.
>   `<media:credit role='uploader' scheme='urn:youtube' yt:display='partner_name'
>     yt:type='partner'>`partner_name`</media:credit>`

Described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Video_Feeds

It's *probably* just a matter of assigning channels which *only* contain videos by a distinct partner to that partner's 'network'. (Or just as likely *any* videos.)

Edit: Since that demonstrably appears not to be accurate, I'll point out that it appears the analytics API does have that information, but from the description it sounds like it only allows reports on channels your own "network".  That being said, SocialBlade has to be getting their information about other networks from *somewhere*:

> Content owners who participate in the YouTube Partner Program can also use the API to retrieve reports that aggregate Analytics data for all YouTube channels that are linked to their content owner account.

Comment: hmm.. i don't think that it works like that. If you take "itsjerryandharry" channel from "SocialBlade" network, and get its videos: `curl "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&author=itsjerryandharry&prettyprint=true&uploader=partner"` each video is going to include something like this `<media:credit role='uploader' scheme='urn:youtube' yt:display='ItsJerryAndHarry' yt:type='partner'>itsjerryandharry</media:credit>`. There is no mention of SocialBlade or whatever.

Comment: Well, clearly SocialBlade is a YouTube Partner.  The other option is that they're using the [content owner reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports#Reports) which aren't available to the general public.  It seems likely they'd nerf the public API if it ever did contain that information. It'd be good to get a "credible or official sources" confirmation on that though.

Comment: @MilovanZogovic Channels like this won't reference the network name "Socialblade," but rather the CMS partner title (In this case "Maker Studios")