# YouTube API - Find User's Partnership Network

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have setup the YouTube API to get various bits of information. For example, if I want a YouTube user's channel name, I have the code:

```
$channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet', array(
'mine' => 'true',
));
$_SESSION['channel'] = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
```

So my question is: with my code setup like this, how can I get the YouTube Partnership network? For example, if the authenticated user is `itsjerryandharry` the program should tell me `Maker Studios` (or `RPM` or `SocialBlade` or whatever it's called now)...

Comment: I don't think there is any API to get the partnership.

Comment: @xuc websites like social blade manage to do it

Comment: I believe they scrape the web page instead of using api.

Comment: @xuc please leave an answer regarding how I might go about doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when attempting to do this, but i managed to come up with this solution:

[How to programmatically find out what channels are part of a given YouTube network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570034/how-to-programmatically-find-out-what-channels-are-part-of-a-given-youtube-netwo/17872113#17872113)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is sure to be helpful for people who need to do this in the future.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can check the video/channel webpage source code and extract the relevant information.

Comment: Can you give an example of how I could do that? I mean like a function - f(itsjerryandharry) should return "MakerStudios"

Comment: You need to study a bunch of HTML sources. It is case-by-case.