# How should i go about retrieving Youtube Partner Channels?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

i'm stuck at an issue with the Zend GData library. I'm trying to retrieve the network names for channels that are owned/partnered by such networks like Vevo, machinima etc.

I've looked into the mediaCredit tag with no success. Can anyone offer a solution?

More Info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php

Comment: Manged to fix my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570034/how-to-programmatically-find-out-what-channels-are-part-of-a-given-youtube-netwo/17872113#17872113

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that info is available publicly via API. But either way I suggest you to switch to [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for new features and support. Otherwise it would be in [channels resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

You can also use [PHP client library for v3](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). Great new features and [samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples/php) covering almost all the functionalities are coming soon.

Comment: Thanks, ive manged to identify whether a channel is partnered or not through the `getMediaGroup()` method. But i'm wondering how socialblade.com do it?